# Regex to Match infinite number of hyphens followed by numbers

Tags: regex

I cannot figure out the regex to match the following:

```
#1234
#1234-1234
#1234-1234-1234
#123524-12123534-123354
#1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234-1234
```

This regex

```
/^#([0-9]+-[0-9+]+-[0-9+]+)|#(\d+)$/
```

matches

```
#1234
#1234-1234-1234
#123524-12123534-123354
```

but I want to do it for an unlimited number of `-873459`s as the user might enter. I've been looking at regex for phone numbers, but that doesn't seem to do it because they cap out at 3 hyphens.

Here is an example in action: https://regex101.com/r/yRSeI6/1

Ideally, whatever it found would be group 1, but that might be asking a lot.

Comment: Is this ok?  `^#((?:\d+-?)+)$`  If not, why?  If it *is* ok, I can break it down in an answer.

Comment: Why do you require two dashes?

Comment: @zzxyz, it doesn’t look like `#1234-` is supposed to be valid input, so I think that wouldn’t work.

Comment: @Aankhen - ah yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rephrase your regex as one or more digits followed by zero or more occurrences of a hyphen followed by digits:

```
^#(\d+(?:-\d+)*)$
```

[Try it out.](https://regex101.com/r/yRSeI6/2)

Comment: That also matches `#-------`, though.

Comment: I didn't consider that. Good catch!